# Powershell Output to File Hits Invisible Border

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

The code below works properly, but if I increment the width 1 more the line gets truncated. Even though there is still more space in the notepad file when I full view the document. Is there a way to increase this invisible border?

```
$table | format-Table @{Expression={$_.Critical};label="Critical";width=35}, @{Expression={$_."Critical #"};label="";width=3},
@{Expression={$_.Error};label="Error";width=35}, @{Expression={$_."Error #"};label="";width=3}, @{Expression={$_."Warning"};label="Warning";width=35},
@{Expression={$_."Warning #"};label="";width=3} > $localSummaryFile
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than redirect to $localSummaryFile use the `Out-File` command with the `Width` parameter like so:

```
... | Out-File $localSummaryFile -Width 200
```